# Scrolling with a mouse on a Mac - either too fast or too slow

Tags: macos, mouse, osx-mavericks, mouse-wheel

I have a Macbook, and love the trackpad. It works like nothing else. However, I've changed the setup of my computer, now use it as desktop with separate monitor, mouse and keyboard. The mouse is a simple Logitech two button mouse with a scroll wheel. I've used these mouses for years, and I like the simplicity.

I have one problem with using the mouse. When scrolling, it starts really slow (1/3 line per tick), then speeds up too fast (10 lines per tick), and there is nothing inbetween it seems. Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue and found that increasing the scrolling speed helps resolving this issue.

In Macbook Air 2019, the scrolling speed is controlled via: 
 System Preferences > Accessibility > Mouse & Trackpad > Mouse Options